# C# correct Syntax for Networkconnection with adminshare

Tags: c#, networking, filepath

I have following, simple, problem because I don't have the luxury to actually debug properly right now. This question might even seem dumb to most but I am still unexperienced when it comes to coding.

I am supposed to write a simple console application that connects to a few different clients (and one server) and replaces some files on the C Drive with Adminrights(If I understood it right that's what the C$ is for?). But because something had gone wrong in the past there are actually a few occurences where the filepath differs from the standard, so I have to check with Dictionary.Exists(path) first, to not make it any longer, what is the correct Syntax to properly connect to said folder?

I was thinking about:

```
    Directory.Exists(@"192.168.xxx.xxx\C$\Program Files\...")
```

I also tried to test it via localhost, but that didn't seem to work because either I am doing it wrong or it is just not intended to work with it?

Comment: For a start being a unc path it should begin with \\ - `\\192.168...`

Comment: @Alex K. Thanks for the tip, figured it out! Can I close my question somehow or do I need to write an Answer myself?

Comment: You can answer your question describing what you did to fix the problem then after a delay you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, figured it out now thanks to a tip from [Alex K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246342/alex-k). Didn't know that this kind of format was called UNC and did some research about it (a bunch of different sites), could easily test it on my own computer like that:

```
    bool test = Directory.Exists(@"\\192.168.10.102\C$\Program Files")
```

Also works with the domainname "localhost" instead of "192.168.10.102". Both resulted in true.